# ImportError: No module named paramiko

Tags: apt, python

I have install paramiko via "sudo apt-get install python-paramiko", but it can't be import in python. How to solve this?

Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import paramiko
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named paramiko

Comment: I have found solution to solve this problem. Following official document (http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html) to install paramiko. It can be imported now.